# Graph API Explorer

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram

```json
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Timeout",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": -2,
    "error_subcode": 2534084,
    "is_transient": false,
    "error_user_title": "Request Timed Out",
    "error_user_msg": "Your query has timed out since you have too many conversations with users who do not have a role on app. Please request for advanced access to instagram_manage_messages permission or reduce the number of existing threads on your IG Business with users with no role on the app.",
    "fbtrace_id": "AJOQB7xEArssyuEvbdMz_jp"
  }
}
```

I try to get Instagram message from graph API normal I have approved this permission: `instagram_manage_messages` but still I have this error. Any way to fix?

I try to add on business manager, I try with and without permission `instagram_manage_messages`  but still nothing.
Facebook fanpage is linked with Instagram account.

From this link:

> Pageid/conversations?fields=id,updated_time,messages.limit(1){attachments{image_data,video_data},from,to,message,created_time}&limit=10&platform=instagram

Answer (score 0):

The following has some ideas for you:

"error_user_msg": "Your query has timed out since you have too many conversations with users who do not have a role on app. Please request for advanced access to instagram_manage_messages permission or reduce the number of existing threads on your IG Business with users with no role on the app.",

You may want to make sure:

- you have a role on the app
- you can try to limit your query to lookup only a few conversations

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: i check all of them and still same error i dont know why, when i try with other account works normaly but only on this account is not working maybe problem is becaus this account have half milion followers and have more than 1000 message per day

Comment: Yes, I think you need to limit the number of conversations you're pulling in a request.

Comment: from the link maybe u can see i put limit 1,so u thing i need to add more or ?

Comment: Try with the lowest limit. If it does not work, it might require one-on-one debugging. You can connect with me on likedin (check link in stackoverflow bio).